# How much would you pay to not have to deal with a client?

Tags: language-agnostic

A friend of mine came to me with a proposal where I pretty much do all the work (design/programming) and he deals with the client. Hes asking for 50% of the contract for the referral and to not have to deal with the client.

Seems like a lot but at the same time I would get nothing if he didn't bring me the client.
I'm wondering what others would do or have done in similar situations.
thanks

Comment: Related suggestion:  write down the business arrangement, even though you're working with a friend.  Some clarity on the partnership now can help avoid disagreements later.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business advice.

Answer (score 12):

Just remember that you *are* still dealing with a client - your friend. When he gets squeezed by the client, he'll presumably be on your case. And, given you have a prior relationship, this could get quite uncomfortable.

Comment: Agreed, you are still dealing with a client, your friend.

Comment: Not only that, but you're now not talking to the source of the information you need to get the job done, but a third party.  Consequently you're more likely to run into architecture/design problems.

Answer (score 4):

Having someone to deal with the business issues related to contract programming might be a good idea if you feel that this is something you don't do well or don't want to do.  Paying 50% of the contract for it seems unreasonable, unless it's actually a partnership.  If you're thinking of a partnership that would require a lot more thinking about how well you would work together and some reasonable estimate of how much work you would each actually do.

Personally I wouldn't want to put someone between the client and myself with regard to the requirements and priorities.  I think that's just a recipe for building the wrong application.  I'd advocate for a closer relationship with the client rather than isolating yourself.

If your friend is willing to go out and find business and needs you to actually get the job done, I'd suggest that you might want to contract with him at the rate that makes sense for you do to the work. That is, your contract ought to be with him. He can add whatever premium seems reasonable and the actual client will accept.  Personally, I'd insist, though, on being able to deal directly with the client on the technical details.

Comment: That's how I would do it too. I wouldn't worry about the client, I would charge my friend what I normally charge, and for him to apply a premium (if there's enough margin for it).

Answer (score 2):

I personally thinks that you should go with the deal and experience yourself with equal partnership.

In future, you can get your own project, based on your current partnership.
Then you can earn 100 % without your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking personally, it would depend a lot on how much handholding the client needs, how much I think my partner would deflect that, and how thin the margins are.

I ran a small freelance consulting business for a few years (put myself through college with it), and had situations where I was the sole interface with the client, and other situations where someone else dealt solely with the client.  It depended a lot on the situation, but there were definitely situations where earned significantly more per hour worked by *not* having to deal with the client, even though someone else was taking a significant cut, simply because I spent more time writing code, and less time figuring out what the heck they wanted.

The best situation I had by far was working with a design house who contracted me to do the backend programming for some movie promotion websites.  They handled all interactions with the client, and gave me very clearcut definitions of what they needed me to do, and were able to answer all of my technical questions clearly and immediately.

If your friend can offer you a situation like this, you're likely to come out ahead.  However, I suspect that given that you're doing design work as well as programming, you're still going to have to do a lot of interfacing with the client, as you iterate on the design.  My suspicion is that you're going to have a lot more interaction with the client than you think, either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

Do not underestimate the marketing/PR/selling headaches. Specially, given the current market situation. Of course, you do need some legal advice to clearly demarcate the responsibilities. Also, since this is the first such job, I'd not mind paying a bit more. Charges always go up on maintenance.